# How to implement fix Bluetooth Device in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, network-programming, bluetooth

I want to write a Bluetooth app without any discovery/scanning.
For that I want to hardcode the server device, which the client needs to connect in the code.

If I use this constructor:

`public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {`

How do I have to implement the device? With a variable of the MAC Address?

If I try something like this:

`device = new BluetoothDevice("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX");`

Eclipse says: "`constructor not visible`"

Answer (score 5):

You can use BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(String) to create a BluetoothDevice representing a device of a known Bluetooth Device Address.

```
BluetoothAdapter myAdapter = getDefaultApater();
BluetoothDevice myDevice;

myDevice = myAdapter.getRemoteDevice("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as @Dennis Mathews says, however the devices *must* be paired before you can send data between them.  That means that each of your client devices has to have already paired with your single server device ahead of time.  This is true even for client bluetooth sockets, at least in my testing on a Captivate running Android 2.2.